# Range of values in Excel

Tags: excel

first thank you for your help. I am creating a simple chart in Excel with x and y axis. The thing is that I would like to define a range of values in order to not put all of them in the cells. Something like this:

```
   x          y
1-128         2
128-1234234 555
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Make a chart of the end points of the ranges.

```
x       y
1       2
128     2
128     555
1234234 555
```

Then select the whole thing and insert a scatterplot with rigidly joined points.  That will do it.